# How can I make static Wordcloud using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-cloud

Greetings to everyone!

I'm working on a `wordcloud` using d3.js.

I'm using the following example [This example is really great btw!](https://bl.ocks.org/blockspring/847a40e23f68d6d7e8b5)

My only issue is that every time I reload the page, the word cloud changes (words gets new rotation angle and new position).

My approach to solve this issue is to have the `rotate()` function always return alternatively either 0 or 90.

But I can't seem to find a good way to make this happen. I thought about using a global scoped variable array:

```
const x = [0,90]
...
d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
  .timeInterval(20)
  .words(word_entries)
  .fontSize(function(d) { return xScale(+d.value); })
  .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
  .rotate(function() { return x[somePosition%2]; })
...
```

But the variable `somePosition` does not really exist. Should I make a global variable `somePosition` and access it in the callback and increment the variable everytime I use it? Is this safe to do?

Am I tackling this problem the right way?

How can I make a function similar to the following one? (I feel like this is the right approach):

```
var fill = d3.scale.category20();
```

Is there another way to approach this problem (something a bit more elegant)?

I appreciate all opinions and solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`d3.cloud`](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) randomly places, rotates, ... words using `Math.random()`.

It indeed lets you give your own angle to the words with the `rotate()` function, but it doesn't provide anything to fix the position of words within the cloud.

The idea, to bypass it, is to simply fix the values chosen by the generator. This way the same words will always be placed the same way.

In order to fix the values chosen by a random generator, we have to [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) it.

As javascript `Math.random` doesn't take a seed parameter, I've included the [seedrandom](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom) library (but there are others ways to use a seed in javascript) and I just set the seed  at the top of the script:

```
Math.seedrandom('hello.');
```

which gives:

```js
Math.seedrandom('hello.');

var text_string = "Of course that’s your contention. You’re a first year grad student. You just got finished readin’ some Marxian historian, Pete Garrison probably. You’re gonna be convinced of that ’til next month when you get to James Lemon and then you’re gonna be talkin’ about how the economies of Virginia and Pennsylvania were entrepreneurial and capitalist way back in 1740. That’s gonna last until next year. You’re gonna be in here regurgitating Gordon Wood, talkin’ about, you know, the Pre-Revolutionary utopia and the capital-forming effects of military mobilization… ‘Wood drastically underestimates the impact of social distinctions predicated upon wealth, especially inherited wealth.’ You got that from Vickers, Work in Essex County, page 98, right? Yeah, I read that, too. Were you gonna plagiarize the whole thing for us? Do you have any thoughts of your own on this matter? Or do you, is that your thing? You come into a bar. You read some obscure passage and then pretend, you pawn it off as your own, as your own idea just to impress some girls and embarrass my friend? See, the sad thing about a guy like you is in 50 years, you’re gonna start doin’ some thinkin’ on your own and you’re gonna come up with the fact that there are two certainties in life. One: don’t do that. And two: you dropped a hundred and fifty grand on a fuckin’ education you coulda got for a dollar fifty in late charges at the public library.";

      drawWordCloud(text_string);

      function drawWordCloud(text_string){
        var common = "poop,i,me,my,myself,we,us,our,ours,ourselves,you,your,yours,yourself,yourselves,he,him,his,himself,she,her,hers,herself,it,its,itself,they,them,their,theirs,themselves,what,which,who,whom,whose,this,that,these,those,am,is,are,was,were,be,been,being,have,has,had,having,do,does,did,doing,will,would,should,can,could,ought,i'm,you're,he's,she's,it's,we're,they're,i've,you've,we've,they've,i'd,you'd,he'd,she'd,we'd,they'd,i'll,you'll,he'll,she'll,we'll,they'll,isn't,aren't,wasn't,weren't,hasn't,haven't,hadn't,doesn't,don't,didn't,won't,wouldn't,shan't,shouldn't,can't,cannot,couldn't,mustn't,let's,that's,who's,what's,here's,there's,when's,where's,why's,how's,a,an,the,and,but,if,or,because,as,until,while,of,at,by,for,with,about,against,between,into,through,during,before,after,above,below,to,from,up,upon,down,in,out,on,off,over,under,again,further,then,once,here,there,when,where,why,how,all,any,both,each,few,more,most,other,some,such,no,nor,not,only,own,same,so,than,too,very,say,says,said,shall";

        var word_count = {};

        var words = text_string.split(/[ '\-\(\)\*":;\[\]|{},.!?]+/);
          if (words.length == 1){
            word_count[words[0]] = 1;
          } else {
            words.forEach(function(word){
              var word = word.toLowerCase();
              if (word != "" && common.indexOf(word)==-1 && word.length>1){
                if (word_count[word]){
                  word_count[word]++;
                } else {
                  word_count[word] = 1;
                }
              }
            })
          }

        var svg_location = "#chart";
        var width = 1000;
        var height = 600;

        var fill = d3.scale.category20();

        var word_entries = d3.entries(word_count);

        var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
           .domain([0, d3.max(word_entries, function(d) {
              return d.value;
            })
           ])
           .range([10,100]);

        d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
          .timeInterval(20)
          .words(word_entries)
          .fontSize(function(d) { return xScale(+d.value); })
          .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
          .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
          .font("Impact")
          .on("end", draw)
          .start();

        function draw(words) {
          d3.select(svg_location).append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + [width >> 1, height >> 1] + ")")
            .selectAll("text")
              .data(words)
            .enter().append("text")
              .style("font-size", function(d) { return xScale(d.value) + "px"; })
              .style("font-family", "Impact")
              .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
              .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
              })
              .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
        }

        d3.layout.cloud().stop();
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/master/build/d3.layout.cloud.js"/></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/2.4.3/seedrandom.min.js">
    <script src="cloud.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```